# how to get json file as input in bigquery view

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a big query table that have below dimensions and i need to filter this table by an input coming from json file that is saved in google bucket loaded every day any idea ?

JSON file should like this one with some filters on the dimensions that big query table have
{ "group_1":"10101_CustReq_STRComp ACC to Front Camera ADAS ECU"}
{ "group_1_filters":"Affected To=System"}

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by creating [Cloud Storage external tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage#required_roles). Make sure that you have granted all the **required permissions**. After creating Cloud Storage external table, you can query it as if it were a standard BigQuery table.

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.group_1_filters = B.group_1_filters
WHERE A.group_1_filters = B.group_1_filters
```

Let the column on your BigQuery table which is table `A` be named as **"group_1_filters"**. Where table `B` is **GCS federated table**.